# Excel Sheet to iPhone Data -- Point A to Point B

Tags: iphone, excel, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data

As simple as possible: I have a very simple Excel spreadsheet with just over 1k records. I want to use this as a static datasource for an iPhone application.

What's the best plan of attack?

Possibilities in my mind:

1) Reading the XLS directly as a data source: is there an Obj-C lib for this?

2) Converting the XLS to a format that Obj-C has a lib for... CSV? XML? some native CoreData format?

3) Importing it into something MySQLish and just getting an XML feed from a server.

I would need some help figuring these approaches out. I've never worked with Excel.

1 would be nice, 2 would be probably the best solution for what I am doing right now, and 3 I pretty much know how to do but I am not actually sure if MySQL has an XLS import (I believe MSSQL does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem at one point. What I ended up doing was writing a simple application that took a CSV file and converted it into a Plist. Then I used the Plist as needed in the app. This code uses [cCSVParse](http://michael.stapelberg.de/cCSVParse). It will use the headers in the first row as the key names to create an array of dictionaries for each successive row. The output is a tidy plist file with all of your data. Use [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:] to pop the data into memory in your app.

```
    CSVParser *parser = [CSVParser new];
[parser openFileWithPath:pathAsString];
NSMutableArray *csvContent = [parser parseFile];
[parser closeFile];

if (pathAsString != nil)
{

    NSArray *keyArray = [csvContent objectAtIndex:0];

    NSMutableArray *plistOutputArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSInteger i = 0;

    for (NSArray *array in csvContent)
    {



        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        NSInteger keyNumber = 0;

        for (NSString *string in array)
        {

            [dictionary setObject:string forKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:keyNumber]];

            keyNumber++;

        }

        if (i > 0)
        {
            [plistOutputArray addObject:dictionary];
        }

        i++;

    }

    NSMutableString *mutableString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:pathAsString];
    [mutableString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@".csv" withString:@".plist" options:nil range:NSMakeRange([mutableString length]-4, 4)];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:mutableString];


    [plistOutputArray writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
```

I also built a pretty simple UI for this. Maybe I'll clean up the whole project and post it on Google Code.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into rendering the Excel file with a `UIWebView` instance, and seeing if you can access the DOM within the web view.

If you can access the DOM, you could perhaps use `libxml2` or a similar library to write a parser that retrieves data from it.