# How to import Excel sheet data into my iphone App.

Tags: objective-c, ios, excel, import-from-excel

iam Working on a application where we can import contacts from facebook,linkedin,gmail     etc,..
  Same like i have an **excel sheet with contact numbers and email Id's** ,i need to import those contact numbers and email id's from Excel sheet.
  I have googled it like hell,found some answers saying that,save excel sheet in CSV format and you can parse it with CSV parser.
   So can any1 Please tell me Which is the best way to import those **Excel Sheet data** into my iphone App.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488948/excel-sheet-to-iphone-data-point-a-to-point-b

Comment: There is a HUGE difference between importing CSV files compared to importing newer xlsx files compared to importing older xls files. CSV is the easiest, xls would be very difficult. xlsx is also difficult.

Comment: I prefer tab separated value files, because commas are so commonly found inside cells of Excel files, but tabs are not.  To get a tab separated value file out of an Excel file, just select the cells and copy and paste them into a text editor.

Comment: would it be a runtime import?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open source C library on Source Forge called libxls that you can use to read a .xls file (the older non-XML format). In addition to that, there is a ObjectiveC framework that wraps the C library called [DHlibxls](https://github.com/dhoerl/DHlibxls). The library will let you read both string and numeric values. The library is quite mature and stable.

Comment: Hi david. Thanks for your answer. I need to get color of row(cell) in excel sheet.can you please tell me how to do this with DHLibs ?

Comment: You probably need to delve into the c code. You will need to spend time reading up on the excel format in the open office spec. Cells have formats, or extended formats. Those have info in them of color.

Comment: Hi david thanks for your reply.. I don't know how to access 'c' code into our objective class. I know that DHcell class will be having rows text,column number,row number. but there is no option to get color of cell.. can you please show me some code to take color of DHCell or row in excel sheet ?

Answer (score 1):

Excel, like PDF and others, is a bloated format that comes in different flavors that have been added on over its lifetime which spans more then a decade.  That is why people urge you to use CSV, because Excel is ridiculous and unwieldy.  The [documentation](http://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf) of the format is 250 pages long.

For XLS (2003 and before) you could consider this library (though I've never used it):  http://libxls.sourceforge.net

However, in my own workflow (in which I have control over the format of data sent to me) I have the authors make TSV (tab separated value) files.  You can just copy and paste your Excel cells into a text editor to make one.  Then it is easy to parse, assuming none of the cells contain a tab character.  You could also go the scripting route.  [Roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org) is a fine gem for Ruby that can handle several kinds of open office and microsoft formats.  If you don't have this kind of control though, then you either have to write you own parser (I'd rather quit my job) or find one written in C or Objective-C.